# Cannot run Unit test on VS 2008

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008

For learning Test Project in VS2008 I followed a tutorial and created a new simple winform application in c#.

I created one class and added a test project with the default created test. When I run the test (right click > Run selection) it is "Pending" forever and after aborted it's result is "Not Executed".

The result details are:

> "Failed to queue test run 'user@user-PC 2014-03-03 13:00:02': Test run
>   'user@user-PC 2014-03-03 13:00:02' cannot be executed on controller
>   user-PC. No agents are marked online to execute test run."

(user-PC is my PC name)

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it [here](http://www.otherbit.com/modules/blog/blogcontent.aspx?id=176).

The solution is very simple: just change PC name (by registry) to an Uppercase name.

Magic, but it solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Please kill the process

`VSPerfMon.exe`

and try executing the unit test cases again.

Comment: Please refer the source: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/299925/after-debugging-a-unit-test-vsperfmon-exe-must-be-killed-to-be-able-run-further-tests

Comment: I cannot find it in processes list